# gitflow with monorepos how to name tags

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am following the git flow model. `feature->develop->master`.

I am also using `lerna` to manage multiple packages in the same repo under the `packages/` directory. as I have 5 packages.

**the problem is the following**: what if develop branch contains updates about 2 packages. This way, when I merge to `master`, I am not sure what tag to create. `package1-v1.0.1` or `package2-v1.0.1` or what exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need tags without mention of the specific package instance:

```
v1.0.1
```

That unique tag would reference a merge commit in which you can *see* which packages were included.
But since your project manages multiple packages, you tag should simply reference the project (as a whole) progression. Not individual packages, since one or several ones can be included at any time in those merges.

Comment: Thanks. So if `develop` contains only single package update, then I create a tag `package1-v1.0.1`, but if it contains more than one package update,  I create a tag `v1.0.1` directly.  But since I use monorepo, I think both of these tags will contain all the packages in the end. So it's kind of confusing that when person clicks `package1-v1.0.1`, he sees all the packages . What do you think ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili To avoid confusion, keep `v1.0.1`, without any package reference, even when there is only one package delivered.